# Why sscanf does not work for this situation?

Tags: c, windows, scanf

Currently I am reading file, and printing (stdout) all words/strings that it contains.

Here is the code:

```
int scan_strings(FILE *in, FILE *out) 
{
    char buffer[64];
    int i = 0, n = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        if (fscanf(in, "%*[^" charset "]") != EOF)
        {
            i = 0;
            while (fscanf(in, "%63[" charset "]%n", buffer, &n) == 1)
            {
                if (n < 4 && i == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 1;
                }

                fputs(buffer, out);
            }
            if (i != 0)
            {
                putc('\n', out);
            }
        }
        if (feof(in))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (ferror(in) || ferror(out))
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

But what I am trying to do, is to search the strings from a buffer which is already read to memory.

I changed `in` and `out` variables to `unsigned char*` and changed `fscanf` to `sscanf`. That however doesn't work. Am I misunderstanding the `sscanf` function, or is there something else wrong in my code?

How I can print all strings from already-read buffer? The data is binary data.

I am working on Windows and Linux portability isn't needed.

Comment: Where is your sscanf code?

Comment: If it's binary data, it doesn't make sense to "read all words / strings". If you're trying to use code that was meant to read words to read binary data, you won't be successful.

Comment: @Claris it's the same code, just some edits which I mentioned. Also, SO would've complained about having too much code in my post (compared to text), so here it is: http://pastebin.com/BvipZGub _Filipe Gonçalves_: What now. The code works fine. What I am trying to do, is to read it from buffer instead of FILE *(which is opened by fopen in binary mode...). I need to "read all words" from binary data, because I need to know if a specific data (already read into memory) contains any strings at all - if does - print them or do something else. The code at the OP is not meant for reading words.

Comment: When you use fscanf it increments the file as data is read. With sscanf that does not happen. If you want the same behaviour you need to manually increment data.

Comment: BTW: Nice correct use of `feof()`, `ferror()`.

Comment: Hint for next time : Post code that's broken, not code that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sscanf(data, "%*[^" charset "]")` works differently from `fscanf(in, "%*[^" charset "]")`.  when data is binary.

Assume `charset` is some string like "123".

`fscanf(in, "%*[^123]")` will scan `in` as long as the `char` read is not `'1'`, `'2'`, or `'3'`.
This *includes* `'\0'`.

`sscanf(data, "%*[^123]")` will scan `data` as long as the `char` read is not `'1'`, `'2'`, or `'3'`.
This does *not include* `'\0'` as `sscanf` quits offering `char` to scan once `'\0'` is encountered.

Using `sscanf()` to scan over `'\0'` is not possible.

---

[Edit]

OP: How should I go about doing it - for binary data(from buffer/variable)?
A: Additional code around `sscanf()` *can* be used to cope with its stopping a scan when `'\0'` is encountered.  Something like just for the first sscanf():

```
size_t j=0;
for (;;) {

  // if (fscanf(in, "%*[^" charset "]") != EOF)
  while (j < datasize) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(&data[j], "%*[^123]%n", &n);
    if (n > 0) j += n;
    else if (data[j] == '\0') j++;
    else break; 
  }

  if (j < datasize) {
    i = 0;
    ...
```

As you can see things are getting ugly.
Let's try using `strchr()` with untested code:

```
size_t j=0;
for (;;) {

  while (j < datasize) {
    int ch = data[j];
    if (ch && strchr(charset, ch) != NULL) break;
    j++;
  }

  if (j < datasize) {
    i = 0;
    ...
```

Getting better and this is only for the first `sscanf()`.

Comment: +1'd. Okay thanks. How should I go about doing it - for binary data(from buffer/variable)? I'll accept this answer a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code never modifies `in`. When `in` is a file `fscanf` will move through it sequentially. But `sscanf` doesn't work that way.

You need to find out how many characters `sscanf` read, and then increment `in` accordingly.

You're already getting the number of bytes read in `n`, so just add that to `in`.

```
 in += n;
```

... after the sscanf.

Comment: You're missing the point that `sscanf()` will not scan through `'\0'`.  Looks like we've identified 2 problems in OP's approach.

Comment: I normally would not expect `'\0'` either except OP states "The data is binary data.".  Hmmm, may code to extract words from an executable?

Comment: @chux That is correct. I am coding a simple pe analyser, but I am not very familiar with all CRT functions such as this - as I usually use WinAPI. Thanks for the answer you posted, btw.